# Could I use WebDriverWait with JavaScriptExecutor?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to initialize variable of `IJavaScriptExecutor` using `WebDriverWait`, not `WebDriver`. Is it possible?
Actual Result:

```
private IWebDriver webDriver;
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor) webDriver;
```

Expected Result:

```
private WebDriverWait waitDriver;  
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor) waitDriver;
```

Or is there an easier way of my trouble?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? You could just use `WebDriverWait` with an `IWebDriver` and then program against the `IJavaScriptExecutor` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. `IJavaScriptExecutor` is an interface that `RemoteWebDriver` class extends. `ChromeDriver`, `FireFoxDriver` and all the other `WebDrivers` inherit from `RemoteWebDriver`, so they extend the interface as well.

`WebDriverWait` class doesn't extend this interface, so it can't be cast to it.

Further more, the [WebDriver API](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/) contains a method `ExecuteJavaScript<T>`. The cast to `IJavaScriptExecutor` is not necessary any more (for versions 2.53.0 and newer at least, not sure when exactly it was added).

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new ...;
webDriver.ExecuteJavaScript<object>("...");
```